# Installing python on sublime text

Tags: python, sublimetext

Need help installing python on the sublime text on a windows laptop. I am new to this and spent hours online looking but nothing worked.

I tried

`tools>build system>new` build system and entered

```
"cmd":["python3","-u","$file"],
```

but it does not work, it shows this message

```
C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in ''
[Finished in 12.3s]
```

Comment: You're getting that error because you haven't saved your `.py` file before trying to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to Tools > Build System and select Python. That should work.
You can just do CTRL + B to run the file.

Comment: I just tried and this is the message     C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in ''
[Finished in 1.2s]

Comment: I think you should reinstall python